# htaccess redirect 301: www to non-www not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect my joomla - site from www to non-www. Therefore I changed my .htaccess file.

I have no experience with changing the .htaccess. So I tried these solutions:
https://tribulant.com/docs/hosting-domains/hosting/9867/redirecting-to-www-or-non-www/
https://joomlagroup.com/joomla-tutorial/redirect-url-in-htaccess-for-joomla
https://joomlaseo.com/checklist/choose-www-or-non-www
[.htaccess redirect www to non-www not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942701/htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www-not-working)
[htaccess redirect for www to non-www not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274893/htaccess-redirect-for-www-to-non-www-not-working)

```
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2018 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems with some server configurations.
# It is required for the use of mod_rewrite, but it may have already been set by your 
# server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in this .htaccess file.
# If using it causes your site to produce an error, comment it out (add # to the 
# beginning of the line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef urls. If 
# they work, then it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need to 
# set it here.
##

## No directory listings
<IfModule autoindex>
  IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations listed 
# below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on Joomla!
#
# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#


# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.katrin\-tilsner\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://katrin-tilsner.de/$1 [R=301,L]


## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Sadly it's still not working.
http://katrin-tilsner.de
http://www.katrin-tilsner.de

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.katrin\-tilsner\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://katrin-tilsner.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

with

```
## no-www -> www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE,QSA]
```

This is what is personnaly used on a recent project and is more generic.

Comment: I changed the code to this, but it's still not working:


```## www -> no-www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.

RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE,QSA]```

I think the rewritecond is not working, because just typing in your code works and redirects me to the www page.

Comment: Oops, I read your question too fast. I thought it was from non-www to www. After a little search I found that : `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is solved... I didn't know that I need 2 .htaccess files. One one the www page and one non-www page. I uploaded the htaccess file from the non-www page to the www page and now it's working.

@Paul Evans: Your code is working fine.